# Supervisord sending instant SIGKILL

Tags: python, macos, supervisord

I am using launchd to launch supervisord which in turn launches a small python file, which is a bot that connects to reddit.

Whenever supervisord launches using this method, it sends an instant SIGKILL. When I launch supervisord manually this process launches fine, and will work until manually quit.

```
2019-03-23 21:06:49,519 CRIT Supervisor is running as root.  Privileges were not dropped because no user is specified in the config file.  If you intend to run as root, you can set user=root in the config file to avoid this message.
2019-03-23 21:06:49,519 INFO Increased RLIMIT_NOFILE limit to 1024
2019-03-23 21:06:49,537 INFO RPC interface 'supervisor' initialized
2019-03-23 21:06:49,538 CRIT Server 'unix_http_server' running without any HTTP authentication checking
2019-03-23 21:06:49,542 INFO daemonizing the supervisord process
2019-03-23 21:06:49,584 INFO supervisord started with pid 142
2019-03-23 21:06:50,653 INFO spawned: 'modbot' with pid 143
2019-03-23 21:06:50,655 WARN received SIGTERM indicating exit request
2019-03-23 21:06:50,656 INFO waiting for modbot to die
2019-03-23 21:06:53,965 INFO waiting for modbot to die
2019-03-23 21:06:57,084 INFO waiting for modbot to die
2019-03-23 21:07:00,232 INFO waiting for modbot to die
2019-03-23 21:07:01,278 WARN killing 'modbot' (143) with SIGKILL
2019-03-23 21:07:01,349 INFO stopped: modbot (terminated by SIGKILL)
```

Comment: Showing the launchd configuration you're using would be a starting point -- though perhaps an even better one would be tracking down where the SIGTERM is coming from (so we can try to figure out if this "modbot" tries to kill its parent, or if launchd is configured for some reason to try to kill its child).

Comment: Re: tracking down the signal's origin, see f/e the dtrace script http://www.brendangregg.com/DTrace/kill.d (Apple *does* ship dtrace, even if it's harder to use than it used to be before they put security measures in place restricting root's powers).

Comment: ...as it is, though, you're asking us to debug a configuration you aren't showing us; sufficient information to reproduce the problem needs to be included in the question itself to comply with the [mcve] definition.

Comment: thank you profusely for your help, I didn't originally post the conf file because it works if I launch supervisord on its own, not using launchd. so I assumed the problem was with launchd somewhere, and I probably should have posted that ini file. I ended up giving up and reinstalling everything and it worked. thank you again for your time.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely (this is guesswork since you aren't including your launchd configuration in the question), you aren't passing the `-n` argument to supervisor to prevent self-daemonization from your launchd configuration.

When the main PID of a program exits, launchd considers the remaining processes associated orphans, and cleans them up.

To avoid this, **never** configure software running under a supervision system to self-daemonize, unless that supervision system explicitly supports following children and is configured to do so.

Comment: thank you profusely for your help, I didn't originally post the conf file because it works if I launch supervisord on its own, not using launchd. so I assumed the problem was with launchd somewhere, and I probably should have posted that ini file. I ended up giving up and reinstalling everything and it worked. thank you again for your time.

Comment: Keep in mind that launchd runs a lot of Apple's internal services; if it were broken beyond an individual process, your Mac would have much larger issues. Thus, it makes sense to start close to the point of failure. (If the problem wasn't the one posited in this question, we'd want to look for other differences between the environment set up by your service's configuration file and that of your interactive shell).